# Programmatically open Notification Center / Today view

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Is there any way (that would be accepted by an AppStore review) how to open the today view of the Notification Center? I searched the docs for `NSNotificationCenter` but if there is a way, this seems to be the wrong place to look.

My requirement is, that I am developing a Today Extension for the Notification Center. The main application is only used to configure the settings of that extension. All content is displayed in the widget. Now I want to implement notifications: If there is new content in the widget I want to send a push notification. When the user clicks the notification in the top right corner I would like to open the Notification Center and focus my widget (if the user has many widgets, it might not be in the viewport).

I have a strong guess this is not feasible. I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have reached a dead-end.
There is no api or event to support display of TODAY notification view. 
It is left for users 'will', when he wish to navigate to TODAY view, as otherwise it can easily become a inconvenience.

Comment: That's what I have thought. Thanks for confirming.